# Retrieve managed object and change value of attribute

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

For syncing between objects in Core Data on an iPhone and server backend, I upload fresh objects to the server, grab a server ID and then save the server ID back to the object.  The presence of the server ID in the core data object should allow me to recognize an item that already exists on the server and prevent the server, on a subsequent sync, from trying to copy the same record to the handheld.

I have this working in one part of my app.  However, when I tried to do the same thing in another place, the sync creates a second version of the item back to the handheld.  I end up with two copies, one with the correct server id and another with a server ID of 0.

Here is code I am using that has this problem. I would appreciate it if anyone can spot my error. Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

```
NSInteger insertID = [jsonResults[@"response"][@"insert_id"] integerValue];//grab id of record from server
NSNumber *newidNum = @(insertID);//convert to NSNumber
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
Contacts *object = [self.managedObjectContext objectRegisteredForID:_moID];//grab object using object id (held in _moID)
object.cid = newidNum; //set c.id to the number from server
NSLog(@"object.cid%@",object.cid);///gives correct number like 2123
```

Back on the handheld, you only see one record in the tableview and its ID logs to 2123. On the server you also see one record with id of 2123. When you sync from server to handheld, the server stays fine but the handheld shows two records, one with ID of 0, and other with ID of 2123.

Comment: What the heck is this line here for?  `self.newid = *(&(insertID));`

Comment: How do you set `_moID`?  How do you know it's set to the correct object?

Comment: Deleted funky line.  moID is retrieved immediately after saving record and set in property.    if ([self.managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
            self.moID = [record objectID];  Yes it could be that I an changing wrong object somehow but what it seems to be doing is creating new object, not editing old one.

Comment: Using `dispatch_async` is almost always the wrong way to handle concurrent Core Data access, and one of the most common symptoms of getting it wrong is attributes with nil or 0 values. Beyond that it's impossible to say without more detail about what "another place" means in the context of your app.

Comment: another place just means trying to do same thing with different entity.  Code should be practically identical but issue has crept in somewhere.  It could also be that first working example is working inadvertently i.e. I am first deleting one copy without realizing it. 0 is default set in xcddatamodel. I am comparing code line by line but cannot find difference. More on point what is better alternative to dispatch_asynch?

Comment: I have figured out that Contacts.object = [self managed....] creates a new managedobject which is why I get two and that, furthermore, the changes to this object do not actually get stored to core data which is why object.cid does not take.  So the problem is now how to retrieve the existing managed object and second to actually store the change to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is I was not saving the changes to the object to the MOC

Adding

```
if ([[self managedObjectContext] save:&error] == NO) {
                    NSAssert(NO, @"Error saving context: %@\n%@", [error localizedDescription], [error userInfo]);
                }
```

solved problem.